# How to have a scratch org open to LEX on first login?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

I'm creating a bunch of scratch orgs to be used for a training workshop, and I've found that whatever I do, the first login takes you to Service Console instead of Classic or LEX. Ideally, I'd want it to be LEX. Does anyone know how I can do that. Here's my scratch org definition:

```
{
  "country": "GB",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "description": "Communities Workshop Feb 2018",
  "hasSampleData": "true",
  "features": ["Communities", "AuthorApex"],
  "orgPreferences" : {
      "enabled": ["S1DesktopEnabled"]
  }
}
```

I create the org with:

```
sfdx force:org:create -f ./project-scratch-def.json -a CommunitiesWorkshopTestAidan
```

Then login with:

```
sfdx force:org:open -u test-xxxx@example.com
```

Which responds with:

```
Access org 00Dxxxx as user test-xxxx@example.com with the following URL: https://customer-customer-7454.cs40.my.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=00Dxxx!SomeBigToken
```

I was planning to hand out a URL to each of my participants, so they could each have a scratch org to play in. Both the `sfdx force:org:open` command and the direct URL open in Service Console, so a few clicks are required to get to LEX.

I did try appending a `startURL`, but that didn't work:

```
https://customer-customer-7454.cs40.my.salesforce.com/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=00Dxxx!SomeBigToken&startURL=/one/one.app
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify *--path* parameter with the *sfdx force:org:open* command to open a specific URL when opening the scratch org.

You need to do something like this:

```
sfdx force:org:open -r -u SCRATCH_ORG_ALIAS --path '/one/one.app#/setup/home'
```

> -r : gives you the URL to open scratch org and doesn't open it up.

See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_org.htm) for more parameters.

So you can handout the URL generated by this to different users and they won't have to log in and would directly be re-directed to lightning setup page.